# js checkbox NOT set a custom value if not checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, checkbox, salesforce

I am working on a form that someone else created that passes through information to Salesforce. But regardless of where it sends values to, the checkbox doesnt seem to behave as it should.
No matter checking or unchecking the checkbox, it will always output the 'xxx' value.

The javascript sets the value of another checkbox inside salesforce based on the first checkbox. If that checkbox is checked, set the 'optin' value to true, if not false.

I feel I need another line of code that says: if checkbox is checked then value=xxx. if not checked, nothing. Then based on that, the other if else can be run.

here is the html:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="xxx" id="industry_optin" name="industry_optin"> YES
```

This is the js: (it is part of a bigger part of js, so there is no close bracket)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

                    $('#industry_optin').on('change', function() {
                        if ($(this).prop('checked') === true) {
                            $('#optin').prop('checked', true);
                        } else {
                            $('#optin').prop('checked', false);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: ready handler is not closed... is that your actual code? did you notice any console error...?

Comment: The value (attribute/property) of a checkbox does not (should not) change with the state of the checkbox. Can you clarify what you're trying to do? Why is the value important to you? Why is the state (checked/unchecked) not sufficient for you?

Comment: Thanks. The value is what populates a field in salesforce so that is neccesary. So based on checked or not checked this value is passed through to salesforce to create a record.

Comment: How are you capturing the value and passing it to salesforce? If you do everything as you should, no key/value pair should be passed when the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know that. I just thought it was sa simple js issue that caused the checkbox to be set to a certain value regardless of it was checked or not. I thought it had something to do with the fact that the actual value was in the checkbox tag. But it seems it's more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has errors because of `});` ending  of code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#industry_optin').on('change', function() {
      if ($(this).prop('checked') === true) {
        $('#optin').prop('checked', true);
      } else {
        $('#optin').prop('checked', false);
      }
    });

});
```

### **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lo4ztLse/)**